# How to loop through SQL table and find rows that match your IF conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's what I would like to do.  Let's say I have a table of customers (Table X) who have entered an amusement park like Disneyland.  This customer table is extremely detailed, with columns like name, age, race, income level, zip code where they are from and a time stamp of when they entered the park.

For each row in Table X, I would like to query another customer-info table (Table Y) to identify all other customers who share common characteristics with the row in question, and who have entered the Disneyland premises at an earlier point in time.

For example, from Table X I'm looking at Joe who is a 49 year old guy from Texas who makes $70,000 who visited Disneyland on June 10th, 2013.  While my loop is on Joe's row, I want to search Table Y for all 49 years old males from Texas who also makes $70,000 but visited Disneyland BEFORE Joe.  I'd like to group the Table X row, and the results from Table Y together (bunched together).  What's the best way of doing this in SQL?

If it were VB I know how to do this using a For Next loop with If statements inside.  But the data is in a SQL database, and I want to learn how to do the equivalent.

(Using SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: Why would the other customers rows be in Table Y if Table X already has that information? Please supply example table structures and data.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  You should avoid looping in SQL as much as possible.  This should be able to happen via a set operation.

Comment: @Martin Well to be honest I segregated customers I care about into Table X.  But in reality, it's all in one table, let's call it Table Z.  So for each customer that I care about (a set) I want to run a query against Table Z to see if there are other similar customers who entered Disneyland at an earlier date.

Comment: @squillman Using SQL Server 2008.  I am all ears, how would I accomplish my end goal via a set operation.  It isn't clear to me because I think procedurally i.e. loop through the set of customers I am interested in, and looking for matches (satisfies my IF conditions) in Table Z described above.  I cannot envision how to do this in a set operation.

Comment: What does "want to group the results from Table Y together (bunched together)" means?

Comment: You certainly should *not* write an explicit loop for this. Rather, you should use a `JOIN`. If you post the details of your schema (table-names and column-names), with sample data and desired output, you'll get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an `INNER JOIN`.

Something like:

```
SELECT
 -- [whatever columns you need]
FROM TableZ t1
INNER JOIN TableZ t2 on t1.Salary=t2.Salary
    AND t1.Gender=t2.Gender
    AND t1.ResidenceState=t2.ResidenceState
    AND t1.VisitDate > t2.VisitDate
WHERE t1.Salary=70000
AND t1.Gender='Male'
AND t1.ResidenceState='TX'
```

Obviously that's assuming column names and datatypes in your table.  The `JOIN` condition will vary based on the information you want to match on.

Comment: Since the OP is relatively new to SQL: this is called a **self-join** and is the usual idiom for the sort of query you want.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  You've clearly shown how I can find other "Joe-like" customers, but that's only 1 row in Table X out of many rows in Table X.  The next customers are Bob, Brian, Mike, etc.  who have different characteristics that I need to search on.  How do I iterate through Table X and then search Table Y using the new & different criteria each new customer in Table X persents?

Comment: Perhaps, in an effort to phrase my question more clearly, I should state my problem this way:  I want to run multiple queries on Table Y, one query for EACH row that exists in Table X.  I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: So for each row in Table X you have different query parameters?  Not query values, but different actual parameters?

Comment: @Squillman Actually, the parameters stay the same and just the values change.  So in the above example, I might want t1.salary=70000 to change to t1.salary=50000, and for gender to flip to female instead of male because that is what the customer in Table X happens to be.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do this:

**Method 1: JOIN**

```
SELECT Name, Age, Salary, VisitDate, Gender, State
FROM
(
    SELECT TY.Name, TY.Age, TY.Salary,
        TY.VisitDate, TY.Gender, TY.State
    FROM TableX TX
        INNER JOIN TableY TY
            ON TY.Age=TX.Age AND TY.Salary=TX.Salary
              AND TY.Gender=TX.Gender AND TY.State=TX.State
              AND TY.VisitDate<TX.VisitDate
    WHERE TX.Name = 'Joe' AND ...

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TX.Name, TX.Age, TX.Salary, TX.VisitDate, TX.Gender, TX.State
    FROM TableX TX
    WHERE TX.Name = 'Joe' AND ...
) A
```

**Method 2: CROSS APPLY** (More complex)

```
SELECT Name, Age, Salary, VisitDate, Gender, State
FROM
(
    SELECT TYCA.Name, TYCA.Age, TYCA.Salary,
        TYCA.VisitDate, TYCA.Gender, TYCA.State
    FROM TableX TX
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TY.Name, TY.Age, TY.Salary,
              TY.VisitDate, TY.Gender, TY.State
            FROM TableY
            WHERE TY.Age=TX.Age AND TY.Salary=TX.Salary
              AND TY.Gender=TX.Gender AND TY.State=TX.State
              AND TY.VisitDate<TX.VisitDate
        ) TYCA
    WHERE TX.Name = 'Joe' AND ...

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TX.Name, TX.Age, TX.Salary, TX.VisitDate, TX.Gender, TX.State
    FROM TableX TX
    WHERE TX.Name = 'Joe' AND ...
) A
```

If you take out `WHERE TX.Name = 'Joe' AND ...`, the query will get you all TableX's rows with all TableY's rows that comply the requirements, without the need of a loop.

Comment: Why so much complexity? Just do an inner join, yes? Or a semi-join if you only want existence rather than comparison.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This is just another way to do the same thing. I will add the join version.

Comment: I'm not really getting the `UNION ALL` either. It seems like if you had new conditions you could just use `OR` and `AND` strategically to do it all in one query.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about the UNION ALL... I used it because it seemed to me that he wanted the results from both tables in the same resultset: " I'd like to group the Table X row, and the results from Table Y together (bunched together)."

Comment: I think he meant, "I'd like to group the results from TableX and TableY together by related values" which suggests to me a JOIN just like squillman's answer.